# Signing a Android App: What about the various fields?

Tags: android, signing

I was wondering about the wizard of eclipse, what the difference was between the keystore password and that asked in the after screen? And what if i post both the same?

Tnk's

Valerio From Italy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what the difference was between the
>   keystore password

The first one is used for unlock the keystore so you can add/remove/delete 
keys which it contains

The second one is the password for unlock the key that you have choosen to use.

> And what if i post both the same?

As you wish. No matter